# Excel VBA - How to Unify Rows

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, row

I really need some help. I have A wotkbook based on a variable called "g/c". The g/c is located in the column "A". There are some duplicated g/c in the worksheet, but with diferent data. I need to unify the in oly one row with all the data. Look at this exemple:

```
 A    B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M  
G/c_______________________________________________
142|  23          4       5           6
412|
556|      2           2            5
263|  6        6                              6    7
111|                          9
142|      5    6
```

The g/c "142" apear in two diferent rows and with different datas. I need a code that can do this:

```
  A    B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M  
G/c__________________________________________________
142|  23   5   6   4       5           6
412|
556|      2           2            5
263|   6        6                              6    7
111|                          9
```

The code need to delete one of the rows with the duplicated g/c (142 in this case) and combine the datas from the diferent rows (23,5,6,4,5,6). I don't need them to merge in the same cell. The numbers 5 and 6 (columns C and D) don't apear on hthe first g/c=142, the same way as 23 don't apear in the second g/c=142. By i need a row with all these values.

I have some code:

```
  'Deletando duplicatas
    ' Get count of records to search through.
    iListCount = Sheets("Automóveis").Range("A1:A10000").Rows.Count
    Sheets("Automóveis").Range("A3").Select
    ' Loop until end of records.
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
       ' Loop through records.
       For iCtr = 1 To 200

          ' Don't compare against yourself.
          ' To specify a different column, change 1 to the column number.
          If ActiveCell.Row <> Sheets("Automóveis").Cells(iCtr, 1).Row Then
             ' Do comparison of next record.
             If ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("Automóveis").Cells(iCtr, 1).Value Then
                ' If match is true then copy the data.

                      If Cells(iCtr, "AC") <> "" Then
                        Cells(iCtr, "AC").Copy
                        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "AC").PasteSpecial

                    'Increment counter to account for deleted row.
                        End If
                   iCtr = iCtr + 1
             End If
          End If
       Next iCtr
       ' Go to next record.
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I need to modify it to do like in the previous example.

Comment: VBA. If it is possible

Comment: I added my code in the question. I don't know much of vba, so i need some help to modify the code, so it can do like the exemple showed

Comment: The code stops when it find the 1st duplicate. I don't know exactly how to do the loop

Comment: (a) What needs to happen when there is a "collision", e.g. the first row for "142" contains a value of 23 in column B, so what happens if the second row for "142" contained a value of 12 in column B?  (b) Do you need to copy the complete cell (i.e. values, formatting, colours, borders, etc, etc) or just copy the value of the cell?

Comment: @YowE3k
a) in case of collision it can be the 2 values. Like "23; 12". But maybe i will think of some msgbox to pop.
b)Just the value